# Non persistent pg connections

Tags: php, postgresql, centos, mod-php

I've changed `pgsql.allow_persistent` to `Off` in `/etc/php.ini`, and restarted apache.

Now I'm getting identical pg handles for two consecutive `pg_connect`.

```
Array
(
[0] => Resource id #14
[1] => Resource id #14
)
```

My question is, is php still using persistent connections, and what should be done if answer is yes.

Comment: Two consecutive connections *within the same script run* though, right? If you run the same script repeatedly, does each run return different connections? Does `SELECT pg_backend_pid()` return the same value?

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, this is within the same script run. If I run script repeatedly `pg_backend_pid` changes, but it stays same within same run.

Comment: Sounds likely that PHP still caches connections *within* a given script run, then. Do you get a different result if you use different connection options?

Comment: @CraigRinger tnx for the hint, when connecting with `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` it has unique connections to the database within the same run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP caches connections within any given script run, so multiple connect calls with the same params will return the same connection.

Unlike persistent connections this caching only occurs within a single script run.

As you found, you can disable this caching with the force new flag - PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW.